# Error in Laravel: Argument 2 passed to Facade\Ignition\QueryRecorder\QueryRecorder::__construct() must be of the type bool, null given

Tags: laravel-7

Generating optimized autoload files
 > Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
 > @php artisan package:discover --ansi
 
 In QueryRecorder.php line 22:
 
   Argument 2 passed to Facade\Ignition\QueryRecorder\QueryRecorder::__construct() must be of the type bool, null give
   n, called in C:\Users\hosse\Project\full\family.mana-group.ir\core\vendor\facade\ignition\src\IgnitionServiceProvid
   er.php on line 386
 
 
 Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
 Failed to update packages for  ./composer.json.

I tried to update facade/ignition in Laravel 7 but it doesn't work